# MessageFormat not formatting when single quotes are included

Tags: java

I am passing in  text which is combination of {} filler and text. I am trying to fill {} with some values and tried using MessageFormat.

```
String sss = "{0}SomeText{1}\'.{2}SomeText{2}SomeText{0}{0}SomeText{2}{0}SomeText{0}{1}SomeText{0}{2}{0}{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}{0}{2}{0}{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}";

Object[] testArgs = {"nits1", "Nits2","nits#"};

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(sss,testArgs));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
nits1SomeTextNits2.{2}SomeText{2}SomeText{0}{0}SomeText{2}{0}SomeText{0}{1}SomeText{0}{2}{0}{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}{0}{2}{0}{0}{1}{0}{2}{0}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The single quote must be escaped using a double single quote:

```
String sss = "{0}SomeText{1}''.{2}S..."
```

Comment: Unexpected but this also fixed my problem :)
Using `template = template.replace("'", "''");` before you call `MessageFormat.format()` is clean.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was, that I didn't use the returned value from method *'format(..)'*

**Wrong code:**

```
MessageFormat.format(sss, testArgs);
System.out.println(sss);
```

**Correct code:**

```
String newString = MessageFormat.format(sss, testArgs);
System.out.println(newString);
```